# I'm not able to validate less than and greater than in robot framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I'm trying to validate 0<4.3<6, I tried with Robot framework evaluate but I couldn't get the result, because I don't find any method to convert string to float, Then I wrote a python class to achieve this but for all the conditions it showing pass

my python code:

```
def should_be_x_than_y (number1, relation, number2, relation1, number3):

    if relation =="<" and relation1 == "<":
        print(relation)
        print (relation1)
        print (number1)
        print (number2)
        print (number3)
        **return float(number1) < float(number2) < float(number3)**
    if relation ==">" and relation1 == ">":
        return float(number1) > float(number2) > float(number3)
    if relation =="=>" and relation1 == "<=":
        return float(number1) >= float(number2) <= float(number3)
    if relation =="<=" and relation1 == "=>":
        return float(number1) <= float(number2) >= float(number3)
    if relation =="=":
        return float(number1) == float(number2)
```

Robot Code:

```
should_be_x_than_y   0  <  ${words[0]}  <  3
```

value of `${word[0]}` is 4.3, so Ideally the case should fail, but It didn't

Comment: For it to fail, you need to raise an exception. Simply returning False won't cause the test to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the original issue is that the `0` and `6` were not in ${}?

This works for me fine

```
*** Variables ***
@{words}      4.8    7.8


*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    [Tags]                             example
    Run Keyword Unless     ${0} < ${words[0]} < ${6}     Fail

Test2
    [Tags]                             example
    Run Keyword Unless     ${0} < ${words[1]} < ${6}     Fail
```

Hope that helps, let me know if it is not your issue!

```
==============================================================================
Basic
==============================================================================
Test1                                                                 | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test2                                                                 | FAIL |
AssertionError
```

Comment: No, the keyword is explicitly converting the arguments to numbers.

Comment: When you say `Keyword` do you mean `Run Keyword Unless`? I was offering a solution that did not require him to have a python keyword at all. His initial issue was that _"0<4.3<6, I tried with Robot framework evaluate but I couldn't get the result"_

Comment: _"When you say Keyword do you mean Run Keyword Unless"_ - my apologies, I misinterpreted what you wrote. Your solution works. If you make a small edit, I can remove my downvote.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am trying to increase my rep enough to be able to comment. Unrelated, thank you for being so active answering robot framework questions. I have been working with it closely for a year and a half now and still discovering new things.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you stated that Robot Framework is unable to convert a string to a Float. This is the basis of your Python development. However, this is not correct. In the Robot Framework Userguide on [Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#number-variables) it states:

> The variable syntax can be used for creating both integers and
>   floating point numbers, as illustrated in the example below...

In the [BuiltIn Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20Number) the keyword for `Convert to Number` also states firmly it supports floating number

> Converts the given item to a floating point number. If the optional
>   precision is positive or zero, the returned number is rounded to that
>   number of decimal digits.

Which means that your comparison can easily be done using regular keywords.

```
*** Variables ***
@{words}    4.7    7.8

*** Test Cases ***
TC
                                           Should Be X Than Y   0 < ${words[0]} < 6
    Run Keyword and Continue on Failure    Should Be X Than Y   0 < ${words[1]} < 6

*** Keywords ***
Should Be X Than Y
    [Arguments]    ${expression}
    Run Keyword If     
    ...    not(${expression})    
    ...    Fail    Number does not match Expression pattern.
```

As highlighted by @Bryan Oakley, it is important to use `Fail` to generate a failure instead of returning a value.